# Date format in reputation graph should use national standards

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, reputation-graph, dates

Date format for localized sites should use national standards everywhere, even in tooltips for reputation graph. Currently *SO in Russian* uses same format as *English SO*:

- Russian

  > [image: ruSOtt]
- English

  > [image: enSOtt]

In other words,  `day-of-a-week, month day, year`. I suggest to swap `day` and `month`, like it is used in the system clock tooltip in MS Windows by default:

> [image: windows]

Worth noting that format in table mode is already correct:

- English

  > [image: enSOtime]
- Russian

  > [image: ruSOtime]

Adding a string with date format into transifex will allow fixing the issue.

Comment: ...or at least an international (iso-)standard, and not a local format (which the us-format is)!

Comment: Note that you can't "localise date" to English, as you describe. Different English speaking countries use different format. Here in Australia, the national language is English, but we format our dates as *dd/mm/yy**. You *can* localise to a country.

Comment: @Gnemlock I don't want to use different format for each contry on the **same site**.  I want to use one of appropriate format for **localized site**. I.e. I don't want to use English, American, whatever else non-Russian format for [**Stack Overflow на русском**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, this is *already* localized, in that the actual format has been put in a localizable string - the order of fields and the actual separators can be changed to suit the language of the site.

We have these localized strings (which are mostly placeholder and separators):

```
"$full_day_name$, $full_month_name$ $day_number$, $full_year$"

"$short_month_name$ '$short_year$"

"$short_month_name$ $day_number$"
```

These just need to be rearranged and the suitable separators used and it should Just Work™.

So, in [Transifex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transifex), the Russian version would be:

```
"$full_day_name$, $day_number$ $full_month_name$, $full_year$"
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but there is still a problem. E.g. about `may` month: in the `$short_month_name$ '$short_year$` result should be `май '{year}`, but for `$short_month_name$ $day_number$` result should be `{day} мая` (the last letter changes). I.e. we need different translations for `$short_month_name$` according to context.