# Date for per day table is not able to localize in reputation graph

Tags: bug, reputation-graph, localization, dates, russian-stackoverflow

Strings with a date for per day table are not able to localize in the reputation graph page:

> [image: dates]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now:

> [image: month date]

But there is [another issue with local date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353547/339911) format related to [Date format in reputation graph should use national standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290392/339911).