# Date format under the list of reputation graph should use national standards

Tags: bug, profile-page, localization, reputation-history, dates

The date format under the [reputation graph](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/name?tab=reputation&sort=graph) in the user profile doesn't reflect national standards (to see the text with year you need to select date range on the lower bar, i.e. not a current year; and then select the day/bar on the top graph):

> [image: month date]

E.g. `фев 14 '17` should be at least `14 фев '17` on [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com). The correct format is already used in the textual representation of reputation on subtabs "Post" or "Time" on the Reputation tab of the profile page. As described on [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290392/339911):

> [image: reputation table]

BTW take a look at [related bug report on ruSO.Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10779/176217) about date format of the moderator election block on the right side of the page.

Comment: Interestingly, at least for that list below the reputation graph page, the dates (at least on Stack Overflow in Russian) appear to display in the right format (day, then month) when the year isn't included – i.e. for posts within the last year – but when the year is included, they display in the "wrong" format (month, then day, then year).

Comment: As a note, [all four digits should be getting displayed wherever we include the year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376047/335251) in the UI... but it looks like that isn't happening for the graph on that page. (Might be something we need to fix? Not sure if there's a bug report somewhere about this already.)