# Newsletter localization issues

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, newsletter, international-sites

Some strings are not translatable (I can't found them in Transifex) in monthly newsletter. In particular:

> [image: asked/answerd]

The translation of one possible ["answered by"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/149840744?q=key%3Ac1c348a55998190ae300e048d0ccb1ad) string is not used here.

Another problem is date in the letter title:

> [image: date]

The date should be allowed to translate and displayed with national standard. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290392/339911) for related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done! the date in the subject was fixed by using [`DateTime.ToString("D")`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_).

For the other strings to be translated on the email, we need to add those translations to traducir (and have them approved). Here are the links:

- Spanish

  - [asked by $user$](https://traducir.win/string/12726)
  - [answered by $user$](https://traducir.win/string/12728)
- Japanese

  - [asked by $user$](https://ja.traducir.win/string/10545)
  - [answered by $user$](https://ja.traducir.win/string/10547)
- Russian

  - [asked by $user$](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11165)
  - [answered by $user$](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11167)
- Portuguese

  - [asked by $user$](https://pt.traducir.win/string/9838)
  - [answered by $user$](https://pt.traducir.win/string/9840)

Comment: Does current culture is set to the corresponding value on localized sites? If you’re using [this overload](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_)

Comment: Yes, we’re using the culture based on the site the email is sent for.

Comment: good. Will wait for a letter with fixed strings.